# Can Mallory unlock an iPhone6 without reception by brute-forcing a 4-digit passcode?

Tags: iphone

Bob has an iPhone6 with encryption enabled and a 4-digit passcode but which is not set to erase data after 10 failed passcode attempts.

[image: iPhone setting to erase data after 10 attempts].

Mallory steals Bob's iPhone from somebody's hand and cycles away. Before Bob can remote-wipe the phone, Mallory goes underground to a location without cell phone reception. She then starts iterating through the possible 4-digit passcodes. Can she eventually open the phone, or is there some requirement where the iPhone must be connected to a network after 10 or so failed passcode attempts?

Comment: Checkout this question [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102693/bruteforcing-an-ios-pin). This answers most of your question. As far as being connected to a network to continue guessing pins, the answer is no. You just have to wait out the lockout timer and try again. Let Mallory know that if she wants to spend 400+ days bruteforcing an iPhone 6 by hand, she can disconnect the phone from the network go somewhere a little sunnier than the subway.

Comment: @INV3NT3D I believe your comment answers the question and want to encourage you to write it as such